# How to delay MainPage, so it starts after data is loaded?

Tags: windows-phone-8

I have an application that stores data in isolated storage. I have a function to read the data (called in Apps.xaml.cs):

await ReadData();

However, before the data read, OnNavigatedTo is called in MainPage. At that point the buffer holding the data is still null.

How can I prevent MainPage.OnNavigateTo() from being as long as ReadData is not complete?

I tried syncing Apps & MainPage by setting a semaphore in Apps, and WaitOne() in the MainPage constructor. This hang the app on the WaitOne.

Any idea how this timing problem can be solved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't delay the loading of the main page - as if the loading cycle is not executed within a timely fashion the app will be closed by the OS.

The best way around this is to create an interim splash page, which will handle the downloading of data whilst showing UI to the user. Once the data has downloaded you can then redirect to your main application page.

Comment: I Read about BackgroundWorker. Will the BackgroundWorker have access to the local variables of the MainPage, i.e. Read the data and deposit the data there?

Comment: Implemented LewisBenge and it works great! Also added: NavigationService.RemoveBackEntry(); so going back will not go through the splash screen.